# How to manage recurring Cloudfunctions with variable timeintervals?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi i am making a Moneymanagement app where i want to have the option to automatically create recurring payments. So when the user creates a transation on lets say 01.01.2020, i would do it like this:

**transaction**

- initialDate = 01.01.2020
- intervall = weekly
- recurringDate = 08.01.2020

then, if its possible, i want to make a cloudfunction  that runs daily and checks

- if recurringDate is today
- then createNewTransaction
- increment recurringDate += intervall

My questions are : 
How do i process dates ?

For example if the 
recurringDate == 28.01.2020 and 
intervall = weekly, it wouldn't make sense to set new recurringDate to 35.01.2020.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Scheduling compute instances with Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule) which uses [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler)

Because of the potential importance of the scheduling, you should strongly consider:

- provide an audit trail of the schedules that you create for your users
- a backup scheduling mechanism for when the GCP are unavailable

Comment: You're welcome! **NB** the tutorial shows you how to schedule things. That it uses "compute instances" as the thing is beside the point for you. You may wish to use Cloud Scheduler to trigger Cloud Functions.

Comment: Okay, so i took a glimpse at GCP and it seems that it only will automate the cloud function call for me. Can you give me a hint on how i should process the date-change based on the interval ?

Comment: You would schedule the Cloud Function calls using Cloud Schedule. Cloud Schedule provides you a bunch of flexibility in defining the periods.